# Why does my ASP Server return this message

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form which I load within a modal window in that from I have used a updatepanel and a textbox named txtAccountInfo. I have set textchange event on that textbox first time change text event fired but in the second time  textchange  shows this message.

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "'Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'uppMain'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" nsresult: "0x8057001c (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_JS_OBJECT)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://firebug/content/spy.js :: callPageHandler :: line 744" data: no]

### my ASP.Net Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="mAddOrder.aspx.cs"  Inherits="iSBBranch.ModalWindow.mAddOrder" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 850px;">      
        <form id="form1" class="form" action="ModalWindow/mAddOrder.aspx" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppMain" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="txtOrderType" Value="p"  runat="server" />
                 <asp:HiddenField ID="txtOrderStatus" Value="n"  runat="server" />
                  <asp:HiddenField ID="txtOrderRef"  runat="server" />
                <fieldset id="AccountId" style="width: 783px; position:relative;">
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>

                    <p>
                        <label>
                            *Account Number </label>
                        <span class="relative">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvestorRef" CssClass="TextBox" runat="server"
                                OnTextChanged="txtInvestorRef_TextChanged"  AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                            <span class="<%=iSBBranch.ModalWindow.mAddOrder.AccountStatus%>"></span></span>
                         <div style="position:absolute; right:100px; top:10px;">
                         <asp:UpdateProgress ID="pbContactAddress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="uppMain"
                                                DisplayAfter="100" DynamicLayout="true">
                                                <ProgressTemplate>
                                                Loading  
                                                    <img alt="Loading..." src="images/info-loader.gif" />
                                                </ProgressTemplate>
                                            </asp:UpdateProgress>
                          </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="columns">
                    <!-- Left column -->
                    <div class="colx2-left">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Post Order</legend>
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Company</label>
                                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="Combobox" ID="ddlCompany" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    AutoPostBack="True">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </p>
                            <br class="clear" />
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Total Quantiy</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="NumberField" ReadOnly="true">0</asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <br class="clear" />
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Matured Balance</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaturedBalance" runat="server" CssClass="NumberField" ReadOnly="true">0</asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <br class="clear" />
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Share Quantity</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtShareQuantity" CssClass="NumberField" runat="server" Text="0"
                                    OnTextChanged="txtShareQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <br class="clear" />
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Rate</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRate" CssClass="NumberField" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtRate_TextChanged"
                                    AutoPostBack="True">0</asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <br class="clear" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Right column -->
                    <div class="colx2-left" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Company’s Current</legend>
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Market Type</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="TextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Last Trade Price</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="NumberField" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Market Lot</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="NumberField" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Highest Price
                                </label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" CssClass="NumberField" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label for="field1">
                                    Lowest Price</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" Enabled="false" CssClass="NumberField" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br class="clear" />
                <div class="">
                    <fieldset style="width: 783px;">
                        <div style="float: right;">
                            <p class="inline-medium-label" style="text-align: right;">
                                <label>
                                    Total Trade Amount</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalTradeAmount" runat="server" CssClass="NumberField" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <br class="clear" />
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="big-button" runat="server" Text="Save" 
                        onclick="btnSave_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClientClick="return $.modal.current.closeModal();" CssClass="big-button"
                        runat="server" Text="Close" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>

            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />


           <%-- <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtInvestorRef" EventName="TextChanged" />--%>
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CenterWindow();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If I close this from and again open the from then no error shows in any times on that session.

Please advise.

Comment: Where is the txtAccountInfo control in the above code? Doesn't seem to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code, this is just a guess, but this error usually means that you are trying to force one `UpdatePanel` to refresh from within another `UpdatePanel`. Are you trying to set a trigger for one, that is located within another? This is not possible.

You are also using a modal window. What are you using to render this? Is it placing the modal `div` within the ASP.NET form? jQuery and simpleModal do not, by default, they append it to the end of the DOM. So trying to update an `UpdatePanel` from inside such a dialog would also give you this error.

Please post some code and people will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FireBug to see if the modal window messes somehow with your updatepanel code. I might have changed the ID.